# SSRS Number value and percentage in One char

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a chart in excel that desplays number values and line graph in percentage. 
Any idea on how I can display the percentage in SSRS.
Please note I can do it indivi[image]dualy in two separate report in ssrs but I want to combine the two. Please see attached image
the bar chart are in Values while the line graph is in percentage
Many thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot a series against a secondary axis, as in your Excel example above follow the instructions from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd207018(v=sql.105).aspx) regarding secondary axes.

> To plot a series on the secondary axis
>
> 1. Right-click the series in the chart or right-click on a field in the Values area that you want to display on the secondary axis and click Series Properties. The Series Properties dialog box appears.
> 2. Click Axes and Chart Area, and select which of the secondary axes you want to enable, the value axis or the category axis.

Hopefully this is what you require. Please let me know if your require further assistance

Comment: Thanks very much Jonnus.

Comment: If you found this helpful please mark as answer using the green tick to the left of the answer.